# How to expose an enum to public API without the implementation?

Tags: java, api, enums, api-design

I have a class which has a property whose type is an Enum. Example:

```
enum CarType {
    TOYOTA("Japan"),
    AUDI("Germany"),
    BMW("Germany");

    public final String country;
    private CarType(String country) { this.country = country; }
}

class Car {
    private CarType type;
    public CarType getType() { return type; }
}
```

The class `Car` is part of a library, and I would like to expose its functionality, so I create an interface which will be part of the public API, and have the class `Car` implement it:

```
interface ICar {
    CarType getType();
}

class Car implements ICar {
    private CarType type;
    @Override public CarType getType() { return type; }
}
```

The problem with this approach is that this would require the whole `CarType` enum to be published. The `CarType` enum might contain additional attributes and methods which I do not want to expose / publish (`country` in this example).

What can I do if I want to hide the implementation of `CarType` but I still want to expose the possible values (the declared enum values) in a way so that the API users can reference them in `switch` and `if` statements like this:

```
ICar car = ...; // Get an instance somehow.
if (car.getType() == CarType.TOYOTA) System.out.println("It's Toyota.");
```

Making the additional attributes and methods `protected` or `private` is not a good solution because then other parts of the library would also not be able to reference to them.

Are there any good alternatives to this problem if I want to keep using Enums?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can provide Enum for public API, and convert it to another Enum for private usage.
E.g. use a Map, where key is public Enum instance and value - private Enum instance.
The problem is that you have to convert data each time the API is called. May require change in many places.

Comment: I'm accepting this answer because I mentioned I want it published as an enum and there is no other way of doing it. Although I went on a different path because I wanted to expose some of the additional functionality (but not all), and obviously it is undesirable to duplicate the additional functionality. Instead I exposed the enums as interfaces where the additional functionality that I want to publish are part of the interface, and enum constants are also listed as interface constants. This solution also avoids having to make conversions and implementation changes.

Answer (score 2):

Although a late one wanted to add my thoughts -

enums can also implement an interface where you can expose only the require details:

```
 public enum CarType implements ICarType {
     ...
      public String getTypeName(){
        return name();
      }
   }

   public interface ICarType {
      public String getTypeName();
   }
```

So that you plan to use it in if()/switch

```
  ICarType carType; //Not referencing the enum

  if("TOYOTA".equalsIgnoreCase(carType.getTypeName())){
     print("Toyota....");
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

`protected`, `private` and `package-private` are the main tools you are provided with for this. If you think about your class hierarchy enough you can probably do something using them.

You should consider composition. Have a `TypeDetails` class, and have each member of the `CarType` contain a `TypeDetails` member. You can then restrict access to the `TypeDetails` getter to only those people who are supposed to access it while having the `TypeDetails` itself visible to all the parts of your library.

Comment: The enum is used from multiple packages of the library, so I cannot reduce visibility. This implies the composition is also not a good solution (because it uses restricted access).

Answer (score 0):

If it is strictly necessary to hide the `country` attribute to user code, you can go for standard visibility (attributes declared without `public`, `protected` or `private` qualifier, those attributes would only be visible for classes in the same package).  I hope this to be useful, but I am aware that is only a patch.

Anyway I cannot fully understand your design and necessities, so probably you have no other option, but maybe what you need is a redesign with encapsulation in mind if you want to protect your code from API misuse

Comment: The problem with this as mentioned in the question is that the enum is used from multiple packages of the library, so the visibility of additional attributes and methods cannot be reduced.

Comment: Maybe instead of this you can try to expose attributes with getter methods and even returning defensive copies to defend yourself from misuse?  If this is not possible, then I am afraid that you will need to redesign your library with a strict division between private logic and public DTOs visible to the API user.

Comment: The attribute was just an example (it's shorter than a method), but the same visibility applies to methods too. The original problem comes from I want to use Enums and Enums cannot extend your own class. With class hierarchy this would not be a problem (I could publish the ancestor class and keep hidden the subclass from the public API).